# MySQL - Inner Joins with CONCAT - Column 'learning_event_name' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql

Getting an error `Column learning_event_name in field list is ambiguous` using the following query:

```
SELECT CONCAT('program:', program_pk) AS global_id,
       program_name AS name,
       NULL AS parent_global_id
FROM program
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT('year:', year_pk) AS global_id,
       year_name AS name,
       CONCAT('program:', program_fk) AS parent_global_id
FROM year 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name) AS global_id,
       unit_name AS name,
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk) AS parent_global_id
FROM unit
UNION ALL
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',learning_event:', learning_event_name) AS global_id,
       learning_event_name AS name,
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name) AS parent_global_id
FROM learning_event le
INNER JOIN unit u ON u.unit_pk = le.unit_fk
INNER JOIN year y ON u.year_fk = y.year_pk
INNER JOIN le ON notes_le.learning_event_fk = le.learning_event_pk
WHERE notes_le.user = '$user'
```

MySQL version 5.5

See [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k3K9B94DUbet7XvUhUKmG9/0)

Comment: Remove the ambiguity - e.g. le.learning_event_name

Comment: When FROM clause refers to more than one table (and/or when correlated subqueries exists) then specify table name/alias for EACH column name used (except output column names used in GROUP BY or ORDER BY). Do this for the last subquery in your UNION (you do this only in ON and WHERE now). And pay attention that an alias assigned to the former table is equal to the name of the latter table (and `notes_le` table mantioned in the last ON not exists).

Comment: Thanks @Akina for the explanation. It would be easier for me though to visualise this as code; could you put it in an answer, or modify the fiddle, or both.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: `notes_le` in the last query isn't even defined.  Your query has additional issues.  Just qualify all the column names.

Comment: I cannot do this - you're the only who knows what table (le or le2) the column value must be taken from.

Comment: I want the result to be all learning_event_names where there is a match with user in the table notes_le, (along with all the previous groupings like program, year, unit )

Comment: strawberry and akina have addressed this. gordon also stated something about 'notes_le' table. and you still want them to write the code for you..? this is not a 'hey write the code for me please' page,, all clues are given: 1. there are more than 1 table that have field 'learning_event_name'. 2. table alias 'notes_le' is not defined anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you want to see?

[image]

```
SELECT 
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name, ',learning_event:', le.learning_event_name) AS global_id, # same ambiguous error mentioned by Akina and Strawberry
       le.learning_event_name AS name, # 'le.learning_event_name' this is to fix your 1st error: ambiguous fieldname
       CONCAT('year:', year_fk, ',unit:', unit_name) AS parent_global_id
FROM learning_event le
INNER JOIN unit u ON u.unit_pk = le.unit_fk
INNER JOIN year y ON u.year_fk = y.year_pk
INNER JOIN notes_le ON notes_le.learning_event_fk = le.learning_event_pk # your 2nd error mentioned by Gordon: this is my assumption, you wrote 'INNER JOIN le' but put 'notes_le' on join and where condition
WHERE notes_le.user = '00082563'
```

as Akina said, we cant do it for you as you are the only one to know whether 'learning_event_name' is from table le, le2, or even notes_le.
we dont know, you know.
the code is just my assumption.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was after.

Comment: take notes on your typo `INNER JOIN le ON notes_le.learning_event_fk` should be `INNER JOIN notes_le ON notes_le.learning_event_fk`